# Angular Firestore query with where returns all docs in collection

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I have an angular app that is using Firestore. Whenever I query for docs in collection that meet a specific condition, the array that is returned contains every document in the collection. I do not understand why this is happening as I am [following the documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md).

On call to the collection in the component

```
this.FirebaseService.getDocsByParam( 'versions', 'projectId', this.projectData.uid )
    .then((snapshot) => {
        var tempArray = [];
        var docData;
        snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            docData=doc.data();
            docData.uid=doc.id;
            tempArray.push(docData);
        });
        this.versionList = tempArray;
        this.versionData = this.versionList[this.versionList.length-1];
        this.initializeAll();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
});
```

Firebase service making the call

```
getDocsByParam( collection, getParam:string, paramValue:string ) {
    var docRef = this.afs.collection(collection, ref => ref.where(getParam, '==', paramValue));
    return docRef.ref.get();
}
```

Below is a screen shot of the versions collection. It shows one of the returned docs, which does not even have the required field.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `docRef.ref` on a `AngularFirestoreCollection` it returns the underlying collection, not the query. So your `return docRef.ref.get()` is indeed getting the entire collection.

I think you can use `docRef.query` to get the query, but I don't even thing there's any reason to use an AngularFire call at all here. Since your code is already using the plain JavaScript API to process the documents, you might as well stick to that SDK in your `getDocsByParam` too:

```
getDocsByParam( collection, getParam:string, paramValue:string ) {
    var docRef = this.afs.collection(collection).ref;
    return docRef.where(getParam, '==', paramValue).get();
}
```

Comment: What is the "ref" in the above snippet? How do I get the data from that return?

Comment: What is the Angular method of getting this data? Is it to use switchmap?

Comment: Sorry about that, I keep forgetting how AngularFire's query syntax works. I updated my answer to show how to do this while using AngularFire to build the reference to the collection. If you want to use full AngularFire syntax, you can do that too. But the code you shared that calls `getDocsByParam(...)` uses regular JavaScript syntax, which is why I answered with that.

Comment: Thanks. This did work, but I am frustrated with the fact that I felt like I followed the documentation as well as possible and I am having great difficulty with the angular firestore docs. They are very confusing to me on a number of levels.

Comment: Sorry about Joshua. If you have an idea how to improve them, the project is open-source and typically quite welcomes contributions.

Comment: I would love to contribute. However, I don't feel comfortable enough with what I have learned to write docs or code for the project. If you have any suggestions on how to beef up  enough to do that, please let me know.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen do you have  a reference to the query method you mention: "docRef.query" ?